# Source of MAC addresses beginning with EE:22:80? (Rogue DHCP server)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I need to find out what device might be using a MAC address that begins with EE:22:80. It is not a registered manufacturer. Google finds a few references to that prefix in various traces people have posted but nothing specific.

The context for the question is that a network I manage recently had a problem caused by rogue DHCP server handing out addresses on a different network causing mass confusion. I found the MAC address of the DHCP server and discovered it was connected to one of the wireless access points, so I used the MAC filter to block it on all of the access points. That solved the immediate problem.

The curious thing is that the wireless network password had been changed only a few days beforehand. Fewer than six people had been given the new password. By elimination we concluded that the most likely culprit was an employee's Android phone. However, the MAC address reported by the phone did not match the MAC address of the rogue DHCP server and the user can still connect to the wireless network.

Is it possible that the phone's wireless hotspot had been active and using an invented MAC address while its DHCP service was handing out addresses?

Comment: That second E indicates that the 2's place bit is set, which means it's a locally-administered MAC address, not one that comes from an OUI assigned to a particular manufacturer. So your question sorta becomes, "Do any known devices/OSes/software packages routinely select "EE:22:80" as their OUI?"

Comment: It could be a VM too, they give you the possibility to change maC addresses at will. Also, contrary to the addresses changed by `macchanger`, they are perfectly stable, as a real MAC address.